# why my combo's store does not delete record

Tags: extjs

I have a tree panel. Each node in the tree has a check box. When users check a node, I add the text of the node as an option to a combo box. This much works like a charm.

When users uncheck a node, I want to remove the corresponding option from the combo box. Sometimes it removes, and sometimes it does not. I have been pulling my hair out for days now. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Here is my the init function in my controller:

```
 init: function () {
     this.control({
         "#problemsTree": {
             load: this.selectFirstProblem,
             select: this.showProblemDetail,
             checkchange: this.handleCheckChange
         },
         "#run-problems-button": { click: this.runSelectedProblems },
         "#stop-problems-button": { click: this.stopSelectedProblems }
     });
 }
```

Here is handleCheckChange function in the same controler:

```
toggleLogOption: function(record, isChecked) {
         var logStore = Ext.StoreManager.lookup("logs-store");
         if(isChecked && logStore.find("text", record.data.text) == -1) {
             logStore.add(record)
         } else if(!isChecked) {
             logStore.remove(record)
         }
         logStore.sync();
     },

 handleCheckChange: function(node, isChecked) {
     if(node.isLeaf()) { 
         var record = Ext.create("GiipIq.model.Log", {id: node.data.id, text: node.data.text});
         this.toggleLogOption(record, isChecked);
     } else {
         node.cascadeBy(function(nd) { 
                 nd.set("checked", isChecked); 
                 if(nd.isLeaf()) {
                     var record = Ext.create("GiipIq.model.Log", {id: nd.data.id, text: nd.data.text});
                     this.toggleLogOption(record, isChecked);
                 }
             }, 
             this    
         );
     }
 },
```

Here is my Log combo:

```
Ext.define("GiipIq.view.Log", {
         extend: "Ext.window.Window",
         alias: "widget.logwindow",
         titleAlign: "center",
         closable: false,
         maximizable: true,
         draggable: false,
         resizable: false,
         overflowX: "hidden",
         border: false,
         layout: 'fit',
         x: (Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width/2) + 2,
         y: 0,
         width: (Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width/2) - 5,
         height: Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height/2,

         initComponent: function () {
             this.items = [{
                 xtype: "panel",
                 itemId: "logPanel",
                 title: "Live Logs ",
                 tools:[{
                     xtype:"combo",
                     width: 250,
                     emptyText: "Filter logs",
                     id: "logFilter",
                     store: Ext.create("GiipIq.store.Logs"),
                     queryMode: "local",                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                     displayField: "text",
                     valueField: "id"
                 }]  
             }]; 
             this.callParent(arguments);
         }   
     });
```

Here is my Log store:

```
Ext.define("GiipIq.store.Logs", {
         extend: "Ext.data.Store",
         storeId:"logs-store",
         model: "GiipIq.model.Log",

         sorters: [{ property: "text", direction: "ASC" }]                                                                                                                                                                                   
     });
```

Here is my Log model:

```
Ext.define("GiipIq.model.Log", {                                                                                                                                                                                                        
         extend: "Ext.data.Model",
         idProperty: "text",
         fields: [
             { name: "id", type: "string"},
             { name: "text", type: "string" }
         ],  

         proxy: {
             type: "localstorage",
             id: "proxy-key",
             listeners: {
                 exception: function(proxy, response, operation, opts) {
                     if(typeof(operation.error) == "string") {
                         Ext.Msg.alert("Error", "Connection to server interrupted" + operation.error);
                     }   
                 }   
             }   
         }   
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **always** create new record even if you are trying to remove. The logic should rely on ids, they seem to be same in tree and combo, and when removing, you should try to find the record in combo by id and remove that. Create new record only if adding.

Comment: I changed remove(record) to removeAt(index), and everything works like a charm. I think there is a bug in remove(record) function as my debug message clearly shows that remove(record) did get executed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. Accept the answer please, if it was helpful.